# What could be the reason for republishing the same job ad?

Tags: recruitment

I have found out from google search that the same position I have applied had been published three times in the last three months discreetly. At different sites I found the following info about the same position from the same company:

It was published between 02 March upto deadline 30 March.

It was published between 03 April  upto deadline 29 April.

And the latest published between 05 May upto deadline 25 May.

What could be the reason they have done this way instead of keeping it open until they find the right candidate?

Comment: Different sites? Or same job site?

Comment: Different sites but exactly the same job. It could be also the same sites but I could only reach those since some sites deletes the info after deadline

Comment: Perhaps they re-posted the post as they did not get sufficient suitable candidates. Did you apply to them all?

Comment: How big is the company? If there are 100,000 employees some job postings can be generic.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep quite big. but what do you mean by generic?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Spending authorizations.** Postings require spending money. Spending money requires authorization and documentation and rules. Plenty of companies are rigid enough that they would require a separate form for each round of posting.
2. **Job site settings.** Many job sites probably only offer 4 week posting options. Allowing people to set highly specific time frames is messy and frustrates a lot of HR types. They want something nice and simple.
3. **Requiring multiple candidates or getting to the interview stage and not liking any of the candidates, or at least not enough of them.** It is not uncommon for nobody good to be identified during the interview phase. That usually happens a week after the posting is taken down, so then it needs to be put back up.

Yeah, it would make sense to just keep the ad up until no longer needed, but like many things that would make sense, that would require redoing all sorts of arcane processes and getting customers ok with complexity. Instead, they just repost as it works with how everything and everyone else currently works.

Comment: 4. The postings are for different jobs, but the company reuses a template.

Answer (score -1):

When I've advertised on a jobs portal, I'd pay upfront for the ad and it would be displayed for 4 weeks. There wasn't a way to pay for additional time or to extend the advert - you simply had to buy another 4 weeks if you wanted to keep the position open on the portal.

Comment: I see why do you think they did three times each month for the same position? Can that be because the candidates were not satisfactory?

Comment: That's the usual reason for re-advertising a position - I've had to do it once or twice myself.

Comment: Very interesting among many candidates they sometimes dont choose any it seems. Did you interview any of the candidates before re-advertising the job?

Comment: Once, yeah: we had a pretty thin number of applicants, and only a couple made it over our requirements to interview. I think one had already accepted a role elsewhere between applying to us and our inviting them to interview.

Comment: @pnatk What do you mean "three times each month"? In your question, you imply that they only did it once a month.